# How do I send the fetch request when the form is filled out?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I am attempting to communicate with an API. I am first requesting a token then storing it. After it has been stored then the user is told to fill out a form and hit submit which will fetch a post request. My problem is right now, the request is being sent on page load and not on submit. Here is what i have so far.

JS:

```
var cred = { email: "xxxxx@xxxx.xxx", password: "xxxxx" };
var credJSON = JSON.stringify(cred);

    fetch('https://app.bl.ink/api/v3/access_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: credJSON,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    }).then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();

    }).then(function (data) {
        var blink_token = data.access_token ;
        var linkInfo = { url: document.getElementById('url').value, alias: document.getElementById('alias').value };
        var linkInfoJSON = JSON.stringify(linkInfo);

        fetch('https://app.bl.ink/api/v3/2070/links', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: linkInfoJSON,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + blink_token
        }

    }).then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();

    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    })

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('something went wrong', err);
    });
```

HTML

```
<form>
  Desired Long URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> 
  Desired Short URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `submit` event listener on your form and make your fetch request inside the handler function.

```
var cred = { email: "xxxxx@xxxx.xxx", password: "xxxxx" };
var credJSON = JSON.stringify(cred);

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', fetchRequest);

function fetchRequest(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // as Mr. Jojo rightly pointed out (thanks to him)
    fetch('https://app.bl.ink/api/v3/access_token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: credJSON,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    }).then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();

    }).then(function (data) {
        var blink_token = data.access_token ;
        var linkInfo = { url: document.getElementById('url').value, alias: document.getElementById('alias').value };
        var linkInfoJSON = JSON.stringify(linkInfo);

        fetch('https://app.bl.ink/api/v3/2070/links', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: linkInfoJSON,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + blink_token
        }

    }).then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();

    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    })

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('something went wrong', err);
    })
}
```

Comment: It seems to be just adding parameters to the existing URL and not actually submitting it to https://app.bl.ink/api/v3/2070/links.

Comment: I disagree with the "my" view,  otherwise I'm going to call the event listener "mine". it's not also the main concept for the question, but you're right it's worth mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem come on form submit which is make a page reload
use [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

in code it look like :

```
<form id="my-form">
  Desired Long URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="url" > 
  Desired Short URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="alias" ><br>
  <button type="submit" >Submit </button>
</form>
```

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
myForm.onsubmit = evt =>  {
    evt.preventDefault(); // disable page reload
    data = { 
        url: myForm.url.value, 
        alias: myForm.alias.value 
    };
    ...
};
```